# Spring MVC redirect возвращает пустую страницу

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect

Стараюсь сделать редирект, но получаю пустую страницу. Вот код:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String settings(Device device, Model model) {
    UserBean userBean = userService.getUserBean();
    ProfileBean profileBean = userBean.getProfileBean();

    model.addAttribute("profileBean", profileBean);

    return "account/settings";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/settings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute(value = "profileBean") ProfileBean profileBean, Model model) {
    boolean isValid = settingsValidator.isValid(profileBean);

    if (isValid) {
        ProfileInfo profileInfo = new ProfileInfo();
        profileBean.copyDataToDomain(profileInfo);
        profileService.save(profileInfo);
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Имя не может быть пустым.");
    }

    return "redirect:/settings";
}
```

Тут стоит добавить, что когда я перехожу по URL: `localhost:8080/settings` все работает и мне возвращается моя страничка. После этого я отправляю пост запрос, который должен сделать редирект, но в ответ мне возвращается пустая страница. Что не так?